# Replacing entire column value in Pandas series based on regex condition

Tags: python, pandas

**What I need**

I need to replace an entire column value in a Pandas series, when the condition is met. For example, consider the following Series:

```
d = ["foo", "bar", "bbl dklha", "bbl hoi", "bbl lala ho", "bbl ljhkh"]
ser = pd.Series(data=d)
```

Which looks as follows:

```
0            foo
1            bar
2      bbl dklha
3        bbl hoi
4    bbl lala ho
5      bbl ljhkh
dtype: object
```

What I need now, is every string that starts with bbl should be replaced with "bbl leerling", so like this:

```
0             foo
1             bar
2    bbl leerling
3    bbl leerling
4    bbl leerling
5    bbl leerling
dtype: object
```

I'm using regex for this (I need it to be regex, this example is simplified but in reality the regexes are more complex).

**What I've tried**

```
ser = ser.str.replace(pat=r'^bbl', repl="bbl leerling", regex=True)
ser = ser.replace(to_replace=r'^bbl', value="bbl leerling", regex=True)
```

But both only replace the occurence of the substring with the desired string, like so:

```
0                     foo
1                     bar
2      bbl leerling dklha
3        bbl leerling hoi
4    bbl leerling lala ho
5      bbl leerling ljhkh
dtype: object
```

How do I make it so that the *entire* value is replaced? I was looking for some kind of argument in `Series.replace` or `Series.str.replace` that does this, but there doesn't seem to be one. I don't want to loop over this series, use a list comprehension or .apply, because this code is going to be run on a spark production cluster where those constructs are unavailable/infeasible.

Comment: Add `.*` to the end of your pattern?

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for being a regex noob. Should I close the question or leave it open? It might help others looking in the wrong direction (pandas instead of regex)

Comment: Leaving it open seems like a decent choice, it could be useful to others say you say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1, using a lookbehind and [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
out = ser.str.replace(r'(?<=^bbl ).*', 'leerling', regex=True)

# or without lookbehind
out = ser.str.replace(r'^bbl .*', 'bbl leerling', regex=True)
```

Option 2, likely more efficient, using [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for in place modification:

```
ser[ser.str.startswith('bbl ')] = 'bbl leerling'
```

Output:

```
0             foo
1             bar
2    bbl leerling
3    bbl leerling
4    bbl leerling
5    bbl leerling
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

try using startswith

```
data="""
            foo
            bar
      bbl dklha
        bbl hoi
    bbl lala ho
      bbl ljhkh
"""

def create_list(data):
    return data.split()

my_list = create_list(data)

print(my_list)

def replace_element(list, replace_word):
    for i in range(len(list)):
        if list[i].startswith(replace_word):
            list[i] = 'bbl_leerling'

    return my_list

print(replace_element(my_list, 'bbl'))
```

output:

```
['foo', 'bar', 'bbl', 'dklha', 'bbl', 'hoi', 'bbl', 'lala', 'ho', 'bbl', 'ljhkh']
['foo', 'bar', 'bbl_leerling', 'dklha', 'bbl_leerling', 'hoi', 'bbl_leerling', 'lala', 'ho', 'bbl_leerling', 'ljhkh']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also check

```
ser.replace({'bbl':1},regex=True).replace(1,'bbl leerling')
Out[9]: 
0             foo
1             bar
2    bbl leerling
3    bbl leerling
4    bbl leerling
5    bbl leerling
dtype: object
```

Comment: It's a funny way, but a few downsides for completeness, this doesn't only match start of string (you'd need `^bbl`), this requires not to have `1` in the Series, and it's also less efficient than a direct replacement/boolean indexing as you need 2 passes ;)